# How to prevent AdMob processes to stay open along with my service

Tags: android, service, admob

I have a service that register a receiver to keep home screen widgets updated (battery).
When the widget is first put to the screen the service starts and sometime it has : 1 process and 1 service (as it should) but other times AdMob processes appears too and stay there indefinitely.
Another way to make AdMob processes to run and stay there when the app is closed (even after adView.destroy(); ) is to open the main app and close it.

The issue seem to appear from android api version 26 and up, no issues on version 24-25 (Nougat).

How to reproduce the issue:

1. Install the [Sample App](https://gofile.io/?c=23DveF)
2. Put the "AdMob Banner Example" widget to the homescreen.

   - the number of processes at this point may vary (inconsistent result) tested on api 26
3. Open the Main Activity and close it.
4. Open "Running Services" from developer options
   At this point you should see 2-5 (varies) processes and 1 service that stay there indefinitely as you can see in [this demo video recording](https://gofile.io/?c=ppWaC8).

As you may understand this causes the app to occupy way more memory than a simple service and will more likely to be killed by the system causing the battery widget to stop working.

I have no clue on how to solve this issue, I tried to seek help in the "[Google Mobile Ads SDK Technical Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/silvio$20pelizzoli%7Csort:date/google-admob-ads-sdk/hckouoAKbOg/7FFEVKdpBwAJ)" but it looks like they haven't any clue on how to help.

Any feedback is apreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @romulus Unfortunately not, I kind of gave up since even google doesn't know what to do or care.